# Why can't I move the std::unique_ptr inside lambda in C++14?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, move-semantics

I want to pass a raw pointer inside lambda, but I don't want it to be leaked, if the lambda isn't invoked. It looks like this:

```
void Clean(std::unique_ptr<int>&& list);

void f(int* list) {
  thread_pool.Push([list = std::unique_ptr<int>(list) ] {
    Clean(std::move(list));  // <-- here is an error.
  });
}
```

I get an error in Clang 3.7.0:

> error: binding of reference to type 'unique_ptr<[2 * ...]>' to a value of type 'unique_ptr<[2 * ...]>' drops qualifiers

But I don't see any qualifiers at the first place, especially dropped.

Also, I found similar [report](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2014-December/040160.html) on the mailing list, but without answer.

---

How should I modify my code, so it gets compiled and works as expected by semantics?

Comment: What is `Clean()`? When I try to repro on clang, assuming `Clean()` takes a `unique_ptr` by value, I get "error: call to deleted constructor of `std::unique_ptr<int>`, which makes more sense.

Comment: @Barry I haven't expected any other error after the original one. Right now I'm trying to fix all others and update the code in the question, so that the original error will be the only one.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to make the inner lambda `mutable`:

```
[this](Pointer* list) {
  thread_pool.Push([this, list = std::unique_ptr<int>(list) ]() mutable {
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^
    Clean(std::move(list));
  });
};
```

`operator()` on lambdas is `const` by default, so you cannot modify its members in that call. As such, the internal `list` behaves as if it were a `const std::unique_ptr<int>`. When you do the `move` cast, it gets converted to a `const std::unique_ptr<int>&&`. That's why you're getting the compile error about dropping qualifiers: you're trying to convert a *const* rvalue reference to a non-const rvalue reference. The error may not be as helpful as it could be, but it all boils down to: you can't `move` a `const unique_ptr`.

`mutable` fixes that - `operator()` is no longer `const`, so that issue no longer applies.

Note: if your `Clean()` took a `unique_ptr<int>` instead of a `unique_ptr<int>&&`, which makes more sense (as it's a more explicit, deterministic sink), then the error would have been a lot more obvious:

```
error: call to deleted constructor of `std::unique_ptr<int>`
note: 'unique_ptr' has been explicitly marked deleted here  

    unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete
    ^
```

Comment: It would be useful to mention that lambda itself becomes a move-only object, so I need to explicitly move it inside `thread_pool.Push()`.

Comment: @Abyss.7 There is no reason to explicitly move the lambda: it is an rvalue unless you store it somewhere.

Comment: @Yakk, yes, I already realized it. Also I found out that such lambda can't be stored inside the `std::function` - at least in libc++ and libstdc++. So, the whole idea seems pointless to me right now, until I implement my own move-only functor object.

Comment: @abyss.7 yes, `std::function` requires copy, invoke`<Sig>` and destroy.  However, if you are doing threading stuff, `packaged_task<R>` is move-only, and produces futures for you.